# Header and footer 100% width, content only 900px wide

Tags: html, css

This is the code I am working with currently: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/39/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
    #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="/"><img src="/static/img/header.jpg" id="logo" alt="coming soon" title="coming soon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/posts/list/">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts/create/">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        There are many sticky footer methods to be found in Google. I've tried many of them and they usually fail in some regards. The problem it seems is that some of these methods are old and may have worked in older browsers but they don't in newer browser releases. Because those pages are old, and were heavily linked too in the past, they still rank high in Google. Many webmasters looking for a sticky footer solution end up scratching their heads as they try these same old methods because they are the first ones they end up finding when they search.
    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    &#169; 2012 Company, Inc.
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
    <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
    padding-bottom: 60px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    overflow:auto;
    background-color: purple;
}

#footer {
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: -60px; /* negative value of footer height */
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    background-color: blue;
} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}

#header {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 60px;
}
```

I am trying to have a setup a bit like here on stackoverflow, where the background for the header and footer extends all the way across the page, but the header content, footer content and main content is in a fixed width column in the middle of the page. After playing around on JSFiddle for a bit I haven't had a lot of luck and I'm sure there is a right and a wrong way of doing this.

Can someone should me the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make your centre column 80% of screen width:

```
#main {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will make it fixed at 900px:

```
#main {
   width: 900px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

EDIT:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
}
#header_content {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_content">My header content, 900px in width</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    My main content, also 900px in width;
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to put the header and footer **content** in the same 900px center column though. If I set the width of the header and footer to 900px for example, it means the background colour no longer stretches across

Comment: You can use a background image, as suggested by Pramod, or, you can define a header div with width 100%, and a header content div inside it with width 900px, margin auto. Same for the footer. I've edited my answer to show this

Answer (score 0):

```
#main {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to put the header and footer **content** in the same 900px center column though. If I set the width of the header and footer to 900px for example, it means the background colour no longer stretches across

Comment: Then you put another div in your header, main and footer in which you put the current code. it then has the css-style from above ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just define css

```
#main {
    background-color: purple;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to put the header and footer **content** in the same 900px center column though. If I set the width of the header and footer to 900px for example, it means the background colour no longer stretches across

Comment: ya i will not stretches if you define the background color to 900px but you can put backgroud image in the body.

Answer (score 0):

As per my underrating I created a jsfiddle. Please have a look and let me know if you have any more issue.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/3Ak7S/1/

**EDIT**

I did some changes please have a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/3Ak7S/5/

Comment: Sorry, but the docked footer is broken in your example :(

Comment: Please check the another jsfiddle. Fixed the scroll issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set your header and footer to 100% width, and centre the content within them, then centre the body.

This is easy enought for the footer, as it is already set to position:relative. Add another div inside the footer which will hold the contents with a width of 900px, position:absolute, left:50% and a left-margin of -450px.

Use the same approach for the header and the body.

Appologies, I would add some code to illustrate but I'm on my iPhone - it would take me hours >_< I'll edit for clarification when I'm in reach of a real keyboard.